# Why filtering data in redux store by favourite is not working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with filtering my data in redux store. I have to filter added films by favourite.
Even console.log(newState) dont show filtered data. Maybe sth is wrong with filter() method? Any advice is welcome. Maybe totally other way to overcome filtering by favourite.

```
case "FILTER_FILM": {
  const statsCopy = [...state.stats];
  const newState = [...state.stats];
  if (action.payload == "filter") {
    newState.filter((item) => {
      console.log(item[3].favourite);
      return item[3].favourite != "true";
    });
    console.log(newState);
  } else if ((action.payload = "noFilter")) {
    return {
      ...state,
      stats: statsCopy,
    };
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    stats: newState,
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter doesn't mutate your `newState` object you should return it

```
const stateCopy = newState.filter((item) => {
  console.log(item[3].favourite);
  return item[3].favourite != "true";
});
console.log(stateCopy)
return stateCopy
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you save me a lot of time :D But now I have problem with restoring data after filtering them. For example when user want to see only favourite films and then back to view all. Maybe you have any idea?

Comment: Depends, there is not a right answer, it depends on your scneario. You have to filter the state? It seems that you could just filter in the rendering method, couldn't you?

Comment: The filtering should be done in a selector function.  Don't modify the state to a filtered version.  Just store the value of the current filter.

Comment: Thank you both. I filtered useSelector and it works perfect :)